# Joining two tables of data via ID but the ID for one table is 5 more that the other

Tags: sql

I'm trying to join two tables of data using ID's. ID's from one table correspond to an ID+5 on the other table.

I've tried using this code:-

```
SELECT
         "Stage",
         "Type",
         "Contract Type (Business Or Personal)",
         "Requested Vehicle",
         "Short Vehicle",
         "Mileage Per Year",
         "Initial Rental",
         "Initial Rental £",
         "Contract Length",
         Opportunities."Advertised Rental",
         Contacts.Id,
         Opportunities.Id,
         "First Name",
         "Full Name",
         "Email",
         "Mobile",
         "Phone",
         "Contact Owner Name",
         Contacts."Lead Source",
         Contacts."Created Time"
FROM  "Opportunities"
RIGHT JOIN "Contacts" ON Opportunities.Id = Contacts.Id  
ORDER BY Contacts."Created Time"
```

This results in only the contacts data showing up in a table with the opportunities data blank. This is because the ID's are different by 5. So I tried:-

```
RIGHT JOIN "Contacts" ON Opportunities.Id-5 = Contacts.Id
```

but that didn't work and I couldn't find anything on the internet that was relevant. Any help would be appreciated as I'm an inexperienced coder.

Thanks,

James

Comment: You need to tell use the sql dialect you are using given you quote the columns and tables. Representative sample data and expected outcome would help.

Comment: Don't spam database tags. Only include the tag for the RDBMS that you are actually using. I've edited them all out and you should [edit] your post to put the one you are using back.

Comment: I'm new to SQL and am not sure which dialect I'm using. On CRM it says "Currently supports Oracle, SQL Server, IBM DB2, MySQL, Sybase, Informix, PostgreSQL and ANSI SQL dialects.

Comment: Also, I can't post any sensitive data but I'm pulling columns from an Opportunities data table and trying to put them onto a Contacts table. The only thing I can find that relates the two tables, consistently, is the Id column but the Id's in the Contacts table are 5 less than the Id's in the Opportunities table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you just tried using an alias for a column?

```
SELECT
     "Stage",
     "Type",
     "Contract Type (Business Or Personal)",
     "Requested Vehicle",
     "Short Vehicle",
     "Mileage Per Year",
     "Initial Rental",
     "Initial Rental £",
     "Contract Length",
     Opportunities."Advertised Rental",
     Contacts.Id,
     Opportunities.Id,
     "First Name",
     "Full Name",
     "Email",
     "Mobile",
     "Phone",
     "Contact Owner Name",
     Contacts."Lead Source",
     Contacts."Created Time"
FROM  (SELECT Opportunities.*, "Id" - 5 AS "ContactId" FROM "Opportunities") AS Opps
RIGHT JOIN "Contacts" ON Opps.ContactId = Contacts.Id  
ORDER BY Contacts."Created Time"
```

Side note, it's probably good to scrub your data to have a cleaner reference than an offset ID if you have permissions to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply however it comes up with this error:-Error Details:
Invalid column used.

* If its not true, kindly enclose the column name(s) within double quotes (" ") if it has any special characters like white space,-,%...
* If its just a string value enclose it in single quotes (eg. 'John Abraham')

Comment: The `*` is just to select all columns, didn't want to manually type them. I've read that if you add the table name in MySQL that should work. Which DB are you using?